# How to add information to (gci -filter *.* -recurse).FullName (ie:LastWrite, Modified By, Etc)

Tags: powershell

I am an absolute noob when it comes to Powershell..

Currently I run a simple script to get a file listing across our server.

```
(gci -filter *.xl* -recurse).FullName > AllExcel.txt
```

It gives me exactly what I'm looking for, a directory path and the file name all on one line across all subdirectories.

X:\00\This file 1.xls
X:\00\This file 2.xls
X:\aaa\This file Too 1.xls
X:\aaa\This file Too 2.xls

Can I add The date/time the file was last modified for each item? {$_.LastWriteTime}?

If so, can the output be sorted by this date/time? Would prefer newest at the top if possible.

are there also options to get who last modified a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a simple text file, I would store the results in a structured CSV file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\' -Filter '*.xls*' -File -Recurse | 
Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime |
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\AllExcel.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

This will result in a structured CSV file you can open on a machine with the same regional settings as yours to open in Excel

As for who last modified the files:
You *could* use `Get-Acl` on each file and with that get the Owner, but whoever owns the file  is not necessarily the one who created/modified it.
You cannot identify creator or user who made the last change in Windows unless have [file and folder auditing](https://www.varonis.com/blog/windows-file-system-auditing) enabled beforehand, so you can extract the information from the audit logs.

Comment: I run this from the root directory and by default the file is written in the root directory. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible. Do I need the Path information? Also I don't care about the Owner only who last modified the file. Is file/folder auditing an administrative setting? I do not have full admin rights..

Comment: @ILoveMadoka Yes, you need to change the example paths I used of course or leave them out completely if you want to run from the $pwd (PowerShell current working directory). As for the auditing setting, yes you need to be admin to do that

Comment: So is this correct?
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.xls*' -File -Recurse | 
Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime |
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
Export-Csv AllExcel.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture

Comment: @ILoveMadoka Thanks. BTW since you are new to the platform, please have a quick look at the [tour]. There you can read how to mark a question 'done' if an answer solves the problem.

Comment: @ILoveMadoka yes, looks fine to me! although the filter should start with `*`, so `-Filter '*.xls*'`, but I guess you did have that and the SO formatting thought you wanted it in italics.

Comment: The code you provided did work but what it did not do was return all the files in subdirectories. Only the root directory files were returned. I have a massive amount of subdirectories

Comment: @ILoveMadoka You left out `-Recurse` then..